# Implementation with TimesSquare in Fragment

Tags: android, calendar, android-fragments

I am beginner in Android programming. I am trying add calendar (https://github.com/square/android-times-square) in a fragment

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "CalendarFragment";

View viewer;
  @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewer = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cal, container,
                false);
    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.init(new Date(), new Date(), nextYear.getTime());

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected time in millis: " + calendar.getSelectedDate().getTime());
        String toast = "Selected: " + calendar.getSelectedDate().getTime();
        Toast.makeText(CalendarFragment.this, toast, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
        return viewer;  

  }
```

cal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
      android:id="@+id/calendar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp"
      android:paddingBottom="16dp"
      android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/done_button"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Done"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think problem is in xml and also few error in java.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: what are the errors that you are seeing? does it compile correctly but crash? If so post the logcat. Or does it not even compile? if so post the errors that are listed, and which lines they occur on.

Comment: It shows "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type CalendarFragment" and "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (CalendarFragment, String, int)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated the code for your fragment.

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "CalendarFragment";

View viewer;
  @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewer = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cal, container,
                false);
    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) viewer.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.init(new Date(), new Date(), nextYear.getTime());

    Button b = (Button) viewer.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected time in millis: " + calendar.getSelectedDate().getTime());
        String toast = "Selected: " + calendar.getSelectedDate().getTime();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
        return viewer;  

  }
```

Specifically,

```
final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
```

Needs to be
     final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) viewer.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

and,

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
```

Needs to be

```
Button b = (Button) viewer.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
```

and lastly,

```
Toast.makeText(CalendarFragment.this, toast, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Needs to be

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```